# How to convert mediawiki syntax to latex?

Tags: conversion, syntax, wiki

I think I've seen a script for converting mediawiki syntax to Latex. Also, in case there are more than one solution for this, it might be nice to summarize them here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) yet. Quoting its website:

> Pandoc can convert documents in markdown, reStructuredText, textile, HTML, DocBook, LaTeX, MediaWiki markup, TWiki markup, OPML, Emacs Org-Mode, Txt2Tags, Microsoft Word docx, LibreOffice ODT, EPUB, or Haddock markup to
>
> - HTML formats: XHTML, HTML5, and HTML slide shows using Slidy, reveal.js, Slideous, S5, or DZSlides.
> - Word processor formats: Microsoft Word docx, OpenOffice/LibreOffice ODT, OpenDocument XML
> - Ebooks: EPUB version 2 or 3, FictionBook2
> - Documentation formats: DocBook, GNU TexInfo, Groff man pages, Haddock markup
> - Page layout formats: InDesign ICML
> - Outline formats: OPML
> - TeX formats: LaTeX, ConTeXt, LaTeX Beamer slides
> - PDF via LaTeX
> - Lightweight markup formats: Markdown (including CommonMark), reStructuredText, AsciiDoc, MediaWiki markup, DokuWiki markup, Emacs Org-Mode, Textile

It's a command-line tool. Usage:

```
pandoc input.txt -f mediawiki -t latex --standalone -o output.tex
```

Comment: I added this as the correct answer, as it seems to be the most up to date and portable solution, as of 2016.

Comment: How about the mathematical formulas? For example, I would like to extract the Spearman's Correlation coefficient formula to a LaTeX file so that I do not have to type it in Latex manually. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient

Comment: @Ahmedov, that works fine.  `:<math>r_s = \rho_{\operatorname{rg}_X,\operatorname{rg}_Y} = \frac {\operatorname{cov}(\operatorname{rg}_X,\operatorname{rg}_Y)} { \sigma_{\operatorname{rg}_X} \sigma_{\operatorname{rg}_Y} }</math>` becomes `\[r_s = \rho_{\operatorname{rg}_X,\operatorname{rg}_Y} = \frac {\operatorname{cov}(\operatorname{rg}_X,\operatorname{rg}_Y)} { \sigma_{\operatorname{rg}_X} \sigma_{\operatorname{rg}_Y} }\]`.  In other words, there's not a whole lot of conversion going on in the formulas.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, which I couldn't figure out by googling: How do you access the medakiwi (`.wiki`) file of an article? And if accessed, that should be saved as `input.text` in that case?

Comment: @psyguy 1. On the Wikipedia page, click "Edit". 2. On the top-right corner of the editor, click the pencil. 3. Choose "Source editing".

Comment: Pandoc converts text and formatting, but does not convert citations.

Answer (score 10):

If you're working from within a MediaWiki, there is the [wiki2latex](http://code.google.com/p/wiki2latex/) extension.

Answer (score 9):

The software doing that is licensed freely under GPL and can be obtained from:

http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Benutzer:Dirk_Huenniger/wb2pdf

You may download the binary for Windows from there too.

On Ubuntu 16.04 or higher it is

```
sudo apt-get install mediawiki2latex
```

and then call the program by, for instance,

```
mediawiki2latex -u https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Ries -o AdamRies.pdf
```

Comment: For http://mediawiki2latex.wmflabs.org/ I get a bad gateway error and the example doesn't work for me as well (Ubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 6):

[Zim](http://www.zim-wiki.org/) is WYSIWYG desktop note-taking application with a wiki markup that can directly export their .txt pages to HTML or LaTeX code. It is available for Windows, BSD and Linux (included in several distributions). It can export single pages or complete notebooks.

A simple page of Zim, their internal wiki code and the compiled LaTeX export as article is showed below:

[image: MWEzim]

```
Content-Type: text/x-zim-wiki
Wiki-Format: zim 0.4
Creation-Date: 2012-10-05T19:09:32+02:00

====== Testing Zim ======

===== Title 2 =====

==== Title 3 ====

=== Title 4 ===

== Title 5 ==

Some text  normal **bold** //italic// __underlined__
~~deleted~~ normal ''literal ''_{ sub} ^{super}

* item
* item
* item

[*] item checked
[ ] item not checked
```

[image: MWELatex]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't use MediaWiki mark up, but its own format

Comment: @AlexeyGrigorev, Yes, but for simple pages can be useful. If you simply make a search & replace from  `'''` to `**` and  from `''` to `//` (in that order, obviously) you can later import the MediaWiki code with bolds and italics working, and the titles, the `[[links]]` and the itemized list are imported without modification.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2007/09/23/) perl script seems to be the script I was thinking of.

Comment: It says: "Update: Don't use this. Use Pandoc instead!"

Answer (score 2):

[Javalatex](http://code.google.com/p/javalatex/) seems like a very interesting project, and should have support for this. (Haven't tried them yet, but will report experience when I have)

Answer (score 2):

There is also [WikiPublisher](http://www.wikipublisher.org/wiki/) addon which is built specifically as an addon to pmwiki. I have been using it with quite some success.

Answer (score 1):

There is a web solution based on pandoc mentioned in other answers.

https://devotter.com/converter

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a chance to test these out, but these three look most promising:

1. [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) ([Web interface](https://devotter.com/converter))

   In Ubuntu:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install pandoc
   pandoc --standalone -f mediawiki -o output.tex input.txt
   ```
2. Dirk Hünniger. [MediaWiki to LaTeX](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Benutzer:Dirk_Huenniger/wb2pdf) ([Web interface](http://mediawiki2latex.wmflabs.org/))

   In Ubuntu:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mediawiki2latex
   mediawiki2latex -u https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Ries -o AdamRies.pdf
   ```

   As a special-purpose tool, this might have better features than the others, but it requires a full [TexLive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX_Live) installation (~2.5 Gb)
3. C. Scott Ananian & Wikimedia Foundation. [mw-ocg-latexer](https://github.com/WikiToLearn/mw-ocg-latexer).

   This is designed for WikiBooks of bundled wiki pages, so it probably isn't as easy to use as the first two.

I found the following projects as well, but they are unmaintained, so I don't recommend trying them unless you know what you're doing. The dates indicate when development seems to have stopped.

4. Szymon Tarnowski, cjiahao, & Hans-Georg Kluge. (2011/2013). [Wiki2LaTeX](https://wiki2latex.wordpress.com/). Server-side. Copied to [github here](https://github.com/simply-hg/wiki2latex).
5. cyrilbuttay, jucablues, pajai, swalter. (2013). [WikiPDF](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:PDF-Generator). ([Overview of code](http://wiki.auf-trag.de/source.html))
6. Derbeth, Sergei Turin, & tuetschek (2010). [javaLatex](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/User:Derbeth/javaLatex).
7. Daniel O'Connor. (2010). [Text_Wiki](https://pear.php.net/package/Text_Wiki/).
8. Chris Wellons. (2007). [wiki2latex.perl](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2007/09/23/). Author now recommends Pandoc.

I did a very thorough internet search, so I believe that this is comprehensive of all software on the internet to convert MediaWiki markup to LaTex.

Answer (score 0):

I think many tools discussed above will fail when a MediaWiki document contains many citations.  The problem is that MediaWiki typically does not handle BibTex files.

One solution is provided by [HandWiki online encyclopedia](https://handwiki.org) on science and computing. It is also a Mediawiki wiki, similar to Wikipedia, but it has some parts that are designed for easy conversion of articles to LaTeX. For example, one can use the standard LaTeX tag "$$" for equations. Also, one can use the BibTeX files for referencing other articles. See HandWiki help page.