# Wiki to Latex conversion

Tags: conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert mediawiki syntax to latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/how-to-convert-mediawiki-syntax-to-latex)

A couple of months ago I came across a tool/system for converting Wiki marked up text
to latex. I did many searches with variety of different keywords, but I am unable to
retrieve it. I am not referring to Deflate.

Do you know any wiki to latex/PDF convertors? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Wiki2LaTeX

Comment: I think [Pandoc](http://code.google.com/p/pandoc/) might help you. `=)`

Comment: There is a (rather new) LaTeX package `interpreter`, which works with lua(la)tex and can translate (almost) arbitrary markup into LaTeX's one.  I think making it use wiki syntax would not be difficult.  It does not "convert" your wiki-marked-up file (well, it does, but internally, on-the-fly), but lets you typeset it directly.

Comment: Thank you bringing that wonderful package to our attention: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/interpreter

Comment: Firstly "wiki syntax" is not well-defined: there are many wikis out there and many different types of input format.  That said, if your wiki uses something based on Markdown then the ruby version of Markdown, [maruku](http://maruku.rubyforge.org/maruku.html) can output LaTeX.  This is behind [instiki](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/wiki/instiki/show/HomePage)'s LaTeX export of its pages.