# Save wiki page in TEX?

Tags: math-mode, import, wiki

Lot of wiki pages are excellent but there is no way to save it in LaTeX format so that the formula are kept. Even if we can use wiki's "create a book" function to save as pdf.

The formula in wiki are just image files, however the html code has the "alt" property which seems is in LaTeX format.

Example: from "[Forward Measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_measure)" wiki page, the first formula is

[image]

while the html code is

> <
>   img class="mwe-math-fallback-png-inline tex" 
>   alt="B(T) =
>   \exp\left(\int_0^T r(u)\, du\right)"
>   src="//upload.wikimedia.org/math/7/8/c/78c74ca7d7162a9d58f72f3fd56d1b09.png">

Is there a way to save wiki page in tex?

Comment: Do you mean is it possible to ***convert*** such a page? You cannot save something which does not exist...

Comment: @cfr yeah, i mean somehow transform the wiki page to a local tex file...

Comment: If you go in `edit` on the page, you can copy the code. Just change the `<math>`

Answer (score 3):

Well, partially: yes. You have plain text and math formulas, as `B(T) = \exp\left(\int_0^T r(u)\, du\right)` in this case, which enclosed into, say, the pair `\[`, `\]` gives exactly the formula shown in your question. One should **only** remove unneeded parts, as an image in your example and convert part of them into TeX/LaTeX commands. This can be done by a program/script, but some manual work may, or rather must, be needed.

See also [How to convert mediawiki syntax to latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/how-to-convert-mediawiki-syntax-to-latex).